# Balanced and Centre-Free Sets of Points

Tags: code-golf, grid

#### Taking in Input

Define a function `f` as follows:

```
IF x < 0:
    f(x) = -√|x|
ELSE:
    f(x) = √x
```

In your programs/functions, each point `(x, y)` given as input will correspond to the point `(f(x), f(y))`. For example, if the points `(4, -2)` and `(-1, 5)` are given as input, your program will be dealing with the points `(2, -√2)` and `(-1, √5)`. From now on, we will be referring to points in this format, rather than points in the format given in the input.

You will take in a set/list of points as input which will then be converted to Cartesian points with the function `f`.

#### Balanced Sets of Points

Denote by `PQ` the Euclidean distance from point `P` to point `Q`.

A set of points `S` is *balanced* if, and only if, for all pairs of distinct points `A` and `B` in `S`, there exists a point `C` in `S` such that `AC = BC`. For example, the set of points `{(0, 2), (-√3, -1), (√3, -1)}` is balanced because the points in this set are the vertices of an equilateral triangle. Note that this set of points would be taken as input by the program/function as `{(0, 4), (-3, -1), (3, -1)}`.

#### Centre-Free Sets of Points

Again, denote by `PQ` the Euclidean distance from point `P` to point `Q`.

A set of points `S` is *centre-free* if, and only if, for all triples of distinct points `A`, `B` and `C` in `S`, there *does not exist* a point `P` in `S` such that `AP = BP = CP`. For example, the set of points `{(0, 2), (-√3, -1), (√3, -1)}` is centre-free, but if you add the point `(0, 0)` to this set, it is no longer centre-free.

#### Formatting the Output

The output will be in the form of a two-digit binary number. Suppose we are given the set of points `S`. After having applied the function `f` to each point (see section "Taking in Input"), the first digit of this binary number will indicate whether this set of points is balanced and the second digit of this binary number will indicate whether this set of points is centre-free. For example, `10` will indicate that the given set of points is balanced, but not centre-free.

Also note that the digits `1` and `0` may be replaced with any truthy and falsy values. As opposed to strings, arrays and ordered pairs are also acceptable.

#### Test Cases

```
> {(0, 4), (-3, -1), (3, -1)}
11

> {(0, 4), (3, 1), (3, -1), (0, -4), (-3, -1), (-3, 1)}
01

> {(0, 4), (-3, -1), (3, -1), (0, 0)}
00

> {(0, 4), (-3, -1), (3, -1), (0, -4), (0, 0)}
00

> {(0, 16), (-3, 1),(-12, -4), (0, -4), (12, -4), (3, 1)}
10
```

#### Winning Criterion

Make your code as short as possible.

#### Credits

This was inspired by Problem 1 from [IMO 2015](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c105780_2015_imo). (Great problem, by the way!)

Comment: Would an output like `[True, False]` instead of `10` be acceptable?

Comment: @Stephen Yes. `10`, `[1, 0]`, `[True, False]` and `TrueFalse` are all examples of acceptable output.

Comment: If I am correct, the points given by the last test-case are `(0,2),(-√3,-1),(√3,-1),(0,-2),(0,0)`. Furthermore the distance between `(0,2)` and  each of `(-√3,-1),(√3,-1),(0,2)` are `√12,√12,4` while the distance between `(0,0)` and each of `(-√3,-1),(√3,-1),(0,2)` are `2,2,2`, but none of the pairs `(√12,2),(√12,2),(4,2)` contain equal elements. Does this not imply it is not a balanced set?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yargh! I made that one up on the spot by taking a rhombus made of two equilateral triangles and putting a dot in the middle. Fixed!

Comment: I guess you want a `10` test-case - would `{(0,4),(-¾,¼),(-3,-1),(0,-1),(3,-1),(¾,¼)}` work (making, I think, an equilateral triangle along with the midpoints of each of its edges)?

Comment: Also for the second test-case I see no `C` for the pair `A=(0,2)` and `B=(1,√3)` so I don't think it is balanced. (I think only 30 of the 66 `A,B` pairs have a `C` in that case)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sorry about all the wrong test cases; I got muddled up. Thanks for the `10` test case!

Comment: No downvotes so far! :-) :-) :-) I guess this was a bit more well-received than my last challenge...

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ạþE€Ṁ
®Œcç€®Ạ
A½×Ṡ×1,ıSµ€©œc3ñ€®Ṁ¬¢,
```

A full program printing the representation of a list of two ones/zeros.

This relies on theoretical infinite-precision floating point arithmetic, which is, of course, not the case. So here is a (43 byte) version which uses a **1e<sup>-10</sup>** leeway for the pair-wise distance comparisons it makes:

```
ạþI€×ȷ10ỊẠ€Ṁ
®Œcç€®Ạ
A½×Ṡ×1,ıSµ€©œc3ñ€®Ṁ¬¢,
```

**[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroWH93k@alpzePqJ7YYGD3d3Pdy1AMh9uLOB69C6o5OSDy8H8g6tA4pyOR7ae3j6w50LDk831DmyMfjQVpDMyqOTk40Pb4Qo2tlwaM2hRTr///@PjjbQMYnViTbUMQaSxjqGQNJExwDM1jUES@iCZAx0dEHKdKFcXaisLkStLkSjLsiUWAA)**

#### How?

(I'll include the replacement code used in place of `E` - equals to allow the leeway here)

```
ạþI€×ȷ10ỊẠ€Ṁ - Link 1: any all-equal distance complex numbers?: list of lists; list
ạþ           - outer-product with absolute difference
  I€         - incremental differences for €ach
    ×ȷ10     - multiply by 10^10
        Ị    - insignificant (abs(z)<=1) (vectorises)
         Ạ€  - all? for €ach
           Ṁ - maximum

®Œcç€®Ạ - Link 2: isBalanced? no-arguments (requires register to be populated - see Main)
®       - recall from register (the points as a list of complex numbers)
 Œc     - pairs
     ®  - recall from register (the points as a list of complex numbers)
   ç€   - call the last link (1) as a dyad for €ach pair
      Ạ - all truthy?

A½×Ṡ×1,ıSµ€©œc3ñ€®Ṁ¬¢, - Main link: list of (x, y) inputs
         µ€            - for €ach (x,y) pair, p:
A                      -   absolute value of p (vectorises)
 ½                     -   square root (vectorises)
   Ṡ                   -   sign of p (vectorises)
  ×                    -   multiply (vectorises)
     1,ı               -   literal [1, 0+1i]
    ×                  -   multiply (vectorises)
        S              -   sum
           ©           - (copy the result to the register)
            œc3        - combinations of length 3
                 ®     - recall from register
               ñ€      - call the next link (1) as a dyad for €ach triple
                  Ṁ    - maximum (1 if any triple has a centre)
                   ¬   - not (0 if any triple has a centre - hence isCentreFree?)
                    ¢  - call the last link as a nilad
                     , - pair with the calculated isCentreFree?
                       - implicit print
```

Comment: The whole reason I added the function `f` is so that people could store the coordinates as pairs of surds without issues arising with floating point arithmetic. Good job, though!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>303</strike> 302 bytes

**Edit:** -1 byte thanks to [@Mr.Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

```python
lambda x,y:f((x[0]-y[0])**2+(x[1]-y[1])**2)
f=lambda x:x<0and-f(-x)or x**.5
v=lambda a,b,p:abs(d(a,p)-d(b,p))<1e-9
def e(k):k=[(f(a),f(b))for a,b in k];print+all(any(v(a,b,c)for c in k)for a in k for b in k if a!=b),1-any(any(v(a,b,p)*v(b,c,p)for p in k)*len({a,b,c})>2for a in k for b in k for c in k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNboMwEIXX8SmmuxliV5j@SKWhF6GoMmCrKJSggCJQ1bNTGyuBRF10Y72Z@d6zPe3Yfx6aaCqT96lWX3mpYOBjbBCHNMzEaA8KgmhrS@lKOZfETHKm42EXqqYUBsVAhyMMQXD/xE7nueI5b2OVd1ii4i2JEm2DaCe1eGGlNqBxT/E@SdGgIm4wJzI2xxqhamCfvbbHqum3qq5RNSOe0EUWM1PMhMdnCU56H1QG1F2SE5fC@RZvS8HJPqKwwuGtDwlq3eD3nP1Db9HfmatLp153/UehOt1BAinbpBhyeCQOKB44COmUFxlfT21vNbPCDsSNT8zQte821TvDf1E@/xqXz8tNHIWMVpgXS8s/h2XA3AYuP3ebWNYQs43GS0nTLw)

Comment: `-1e-9<d(a,p)-d(b,p)<1e-9` means `abs(d(a,p)-d(b,p))<1e-9` ([302 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZBNboMwEIXX8SmmuxliV5j@SKWhF6GoMmCrKJSggCJQ1bNTGyuBRF10Y72Z@d6zPe3Yfx6aaCqT96lWX3mpYOBjbBCHNMzEaA8KgmhrS@lKOZfETHKm42EXqqYUBsVAhyMMQXD/xE7nueI5b2OVd1ii4i2JEm2DaCe1eGGlNqBxT/E@SdGgIm4wJzI2xxqhamCfvbbHqum3qq5RNSOe0EUWM1PMhMdnCU56H1QG1F2SE5fC@RZvS8HJPqKwwuGtDwlq3eD3nP1Db9HfmatLp153/UehOt1BAinbpBhyeCQOKB44COmUFxlfT21vNbPCDsSNT8zQte821TvDf1E@/xqXz8tNHIWMVpgXS8s/h2XA3AYuP3ebWNYQs43GS0nTLw))

Comment: I do Python golf a lot, but I've never come across the `all` and `any` functions. What do they do?

Comment: @J843136028 ```all``` returns true if all the values in the argument (which must be iterable) are true, while ```any``` returns true if at least on of the values in the argument are true.

Comment: @HalvardHummel Thank you!